# how to save PDF metadata to AzureBlob

Tags: java, azure-blob-storage

how to save metadata of Original PDF while uploading file to BLOB

I save file to Blob using openOutPutStream  and while reading it i parse the content using Tika which gives me Metadata of the file in return

```
Inputstream is = newBlobReference.openInputStream();    
BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
            Metadata metaData = new Metadata();
            ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
            PDFParser parser = new PDFParser();
            String content = "";
            parser.parse(is, handler, metaData, context);
```

just to get few Metadata(Creation-Date/xmpTPg:NPages) of pdf i have to parse the file using Tika . is there a way to save metadata to BLOB while uploading the PDF

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to get the data during the upload process from azure blob storage. The metadata can be set and retrieved when the blob has been established/created within azure blob storage, more on this can be found on this **[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata)** , there are also other alternatives such as [Azure indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage) which would also require the blobs to reside in storage. My recommendation would be to use the method you are using, then append that information into a separate blob that would keep that metadata.

Comment: I have already checked the link , but just wanted to try my luck , to check if there is more optimised solution . I also have a requirement to save md5 of document and use it to avoid duplicates . i have used Options.setStoreBlobContentMD5 but i am dont know how can i use this to filter out duplicates before persisting the PDF to Blob. i know i can avoid duplicates using Blob name but can this be done using MD5 too ?